# How to customize the default error message input string is not in correct format

Tags: silverlight

one question
In in silver light I have text box i bind it with DateTime? property
when i insert wrong Date in text box it give error input string is not in correct format
this is default message how i can customize this msg
can any one help me
how can i customize this msg input string is not in correct format
??

Comment: Where does the error come up? Is this an error you want to show to the user?

Comment: The error is "Input String is not in correct format" ... I want to show the user that "Only Numbers are allowed" ....